# Como eu poderia gerar um xml em java?

Tags: java

Semelhante a este aqui, neste formato. Este código será gerado através de um evento de um botão.

```
<items><variable name="id"type="int">6</variable>
<itens><variable name="pos"type="int">0</variable>
<itens><variable name="count"type="int">1</variable>
<itens><variable name="id"type="int">6</variable>
<itens><variable name="max_count"type="int">1</variable>
<variable name="data"
type="octets">0100ff0001000000010000003c8601002c00020000000000010000000100000000000000009f8601009f860100e7030000e7030000050000000000404000c07944040000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000a62500009f860100a62500009f860100442100009f8601001001145000092000000385b0100</variable>
<itens><variable name="proctype"type="int">32791</variable>
<itens><variable name="expire_date"type="int">0</variable>
<itens><variable name="guid1"type="int">0</variable>
<itens><variable name="guid2"type="int">0</variable>
<itens><variable name="mask"type="int">1</variable>
</items>
```

Comment: se a gente pensar que XMLé só uma padronização, você pode gerar como uma string no padrão que quiser e depois salvar com a extensão XML.

Comment: Coloque mais exemplos do seu código para a gente conseguir ajudar, da onde vem esses valores, quer salvar como e onde? Deixe a pergunta mais completa possivel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baixe essa biblioteca http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.11.1/xstream-1.4.11.1.jar

E adiciona o jar no projeto

```
public class ManipuladorXml {

public  boolean gravarXml(List<Usuario>usuarios,String nome) {
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    String xml = xstream.toXML(usuarios);
    try {
        SalvarArquivo(nome,xml);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ManipuladorXml.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return false;
}

  public void lerXml(String nome) throws FileNotFoundException {
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Usuario> dados =  (List<Usuario>) xstream.fromXML(new FileReader(nome+".xml"));
    for (Usuario dado : dados) {
        System.out.println(dado.getNome());
        System.out.println(dado.getIdade());
    }
}

private void SalvarArquivo(String nome,String xml) throws IOException {
    FileWriter arq = new FileWriter(nome + ".xml");
    PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(arq);
    gravarArq.printf(xml);
    arq.close();
}
}



public class Usuario {

private String nome;
private int idade;

public Usuario(String nomeUsuario, int serial) {
    super();
    this.nome = nomeUsuario;
    this.idade = serial;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return nome + " - " + idade;
}

public String getNome() {
    return this.nome;
}

public int getIdade() {
    return this.idade;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public void setIdade(int idade) {
    this.idade = idade;
}
}

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ManipuladorXml xml =new ManipuladorXml();
    List<Usuario>usuarios = new ArrayList<>();
    Usuario u = new Usuario("test1", 1);
    Usuario u1 = new Usuario("teste2", 3);
    Usuario u2 = new Usuario("test3", 4);
    usuarios.add(u);
    usuarios.add(u1);
    usuarios.add(u2);
    xml.gravarXml(usuarios,"usuarios");
    try {
        xml.lerXml("usuarios");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }       
}    
}
```